# Can't detect realtek RTL8101E/RTL8102E ethernet controller

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

**I need some body give me insight in this issue:**

i have damn toshiba satlellite C850-A989 with ubuntu 13.10 installed, the wireless card work fine. BUT the ethernet controller not working.
and i dont know if i have problem in my preinstalled (default) driver or not.

this is a output of:

```
$lspci
:02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
:03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
$ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
    inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:41 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:41 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:4169 (4.1 KB)  TX bytes:4169 (4.1 KB)
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:ec:99:3f:a9:ee
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I downlaoded the RTL8101E/RTL8102E driver from official realtek website from 
[this link:](http://www.realtek.com.tw/DOWNLOADS/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false)

and I start installing the driver from source code, but ending with error

```
make[3]: *** [/home/manee/Downloads/r8101-1.024.00/src/r8101_n.o]  Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/manee/Downloads/r8101-1.024.00/src]  Error 2
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I looked into code.google and I found there is a patch must be putted in src folder, I putted the patch but the same error still there.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lspci -nnk -s 00:03:00.0`? Also `dmesg | grep -E 'eth|too'` and `nm-cli`. Edit your question and add the information.

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: From the this morning i start over again, but ended with a bug in the 3.11.0-14-generic kernel, the bug says the r8168-8.036.00,(which is the patch) fails to compile under 3.11.0-rc7

Comment: This is patch name put it in google to see more details about this bug r8168-8.036.00-kernel-3.10.10.patch

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my previous answer (comment), I suggest that you either (a) verify that the realtek adapter is working fine with a different OS (e.g., windows), or (b) assume that your initial attempt to set up the system with default drivers has corrupted the internal settings of the adapter and will require a loss of power to reset. In case of (b), remove (or disconnect) the battery from the system for a few minutes, then hook it back up and then try reinstalling the driver, with the patches in the proper location, etc.

Comment: I did this step yester day but no new, I will try to reinstall this driver again, really thank you for taking time answering me.